# Proximity Node with 'Expansion/Contamination' process

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

How to make a proximity shader that scales exponentially as something gets closer and closer?

The idea is when an object is close, the color ramp won't trigger, only when is almost there it start to expand exponentially the closer it gets.

There are a lot of cool things that can be done with it. Unfortunately I can only enhance the damn thing contrast and dance around a little bit with it. Here is an image sequence to portray what I mean.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

that can be this kind of settings:

[image]

So you have:

[image]

Values above are to be tuned to your needs.

Comment: Um, I see, but it's not quite that. Imagine an object touching other squish one and it spreads all over, or touching water and forming the waves. I'm trying to fake that. This example u made the coloramp is just enhancing intensity, I want it to spread u know? But only when very close to the mesh.

Comment: It's just like plugin the proximity directly in the coloramp, but with an exponential increase to the radius of the color. And preserving the smoothness of the color border.

Comment: You probably want to remove "exponent" and add "power" before "map range", then adjust the exponent of the "power" and the min/max values of map range.

Comment: It's a good result, but the expansion is easing out the closer it gets, I want it to accelerate instead. Thanks for the help so far!